# IEqualityComparer for Tuples

Tags: c#

I am using Tuples of 2, 3 and 4 Decimals such as:

```
(Decimal? x, Decimal? y, Decimal? z) p1 = (1.25m, 2.12m, 3.14m);

(Decimal? x, Decimal? y, Decimal? z) p2 = (1.24m, 2.11m, 3.16m);
```

I need to check if `p1` equals `p2` by comparing each `Decimal?` value.

For comparing two decimal values I have the following `IEqualityComparer`:

```
  public class DecimalToleranceEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Decimal?> {

    private readonly Decimal _tolerance;

    public DecimalToleranceEqualityComparer(Decimal tolerance) {
      _tolerance = tolerance;
    }

    public Boolean Equals(Decimal? x, Decimal? y) {

      if (!x.HasValue && !y.HasValue)
        return true;

      else if (!x.HasValue || !y.HasValue)
        return false;

      else
        return Math.Abs(x.Value - y.Value) <= _tolerance;

    }

    public Int32 GetHashCode(Decimal? obj) {
      return obj.GetHashCode();
    }

  }
```

How to create EqualityComparers for Tuples?

Comment: Do you mean `(Decimal? x, Decimal? y, Decimal? z) p2 = (1.24m, 2.11m, 3.16m);` ?  (you have `p1` in your question)

Comment: Yes, just corrected it. I need to compare the two tuples `p1` and `p2`

Comment: You have the Comparer. All you need is a Comparator. Either create an extension method, or define a delegate or create a static helper.

Answer (score 0):

I see two main issues with your decimal comparer, both stemming from the allowance of a "tolerance":

1. `GetHashCode` is incompatible with `Equals' - two decimals that are "equal" could have different hash codes.
2. `Equals` is not transitive. Say your tolerance was 1. Then 1.2 and 2.0 would be "equal", and 2.0 and 2.9 would be "equal", but 1.2 and 2.9 would not be "equal". A non-transitive equality can be problematic.

If you ignore the tolerance, then you can just use the built-in equality for decimals (and tuples) that does not have these problems.

But, for fun, one implementation could be to use the comparer you have (or the default `Double?` comparer, and compare p1.Item1 with p2.Item1, etc.:

```
public class DecimalTupleEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<(Decimal?,Decimal?,Decimal?)> {

    private readonly Decimal _tolerance;
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<Decimal?> _comparer;

    public DecimalTupleEqualityComparer(Decimal tolerance) : this(tolerance, null) {}
    public DecimalTupleEqualityComparer(Decimal tolerance, IEqualityComparer<Decimal?> comparer) {
        if (comparer==null)
        {
            _comparer = EqualityComparer<Decimal?>.Default;
        }
        else
        {
            _comparer = comparer;
        }
    }

    public Boolean Equals((Decimal?,Decimal?,Decimal?) x, (Decimal?,Decimal?,Decimal?) y) {
    
        foreach (var (v1,v2) in new[] {(x.Item1, y.Item1), (x.Item2, y.Item2),(x.Item3, y.Item3)})
            if (!_comparer.Equals(v1,v2))
                return false;
        
        return true;
    }

    public Int32 GetHashCode((Decimal?,Decimal?,Decimal?)  obj) {
      return obj.Item1.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Item2.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Item2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you fix the 2 problems you pointed? I need to use a tolerance as I am using this on Unit Tests where I consider 2.21 and 2.22 equal enough ...

Comment: I don't know that there''s a way to define an equality comparer with a tolerance that is transitive. If all you're using them for is in unit tests, you could just do the comparison in the unit test rather then defining an equality comparer. That said, it's only a problem if you're using the comparer as a lookup key or something that requires transitivity. If it's not creating a problem ho you're using it then it may nod need to be fixed.

Comment: I agree with @DStanley. Assuming you could magically fix #2, how would you fix #1? What "rule" could you come up with to make two hash codes be the same for two decimals that would be equal within tolerance? You'd have to normalize the hash codes in some way. It seems like the hash's would devolve to the worst case: all of them equal! That defeats the purpose of a hash altogether. Perhaps the only way I can see to fix this would be to force all your decimals to identical precisions and get rid of the notion of tolerance; in that case you'd be able to make it consistent and deterministic.

Comment: You _could_ round each value to some number of decimals (which could also be used for your hash code), but then you have weird situations like where 1.51 and 2.49 are equal, but 2.49 and 2.51 are not.

Comment: Yeah that's kind of what I was thinking by "force to identical precision". Guess I could have used "round" here :) But, it comes back to the same problem as you noted.